# How to get device Id in expo react native app

Tags: react-native, expo, hybrid-mobile-app, deviceid, react-native-device-info

I am implementing API to connect app with server. I have to use deviceId there. As mentioned in [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) we can use third party library 'react-native-device-info'. But when I am using it I am getting errors as attached screenshots. As per error it's saying to do linking but as I am using react version 0.62, so autolinking is there. So What can be issue? It took too much time to search it but till now I didn't get a proper solution.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

react-native-device-info library  wont work in Expo , since it requires linking of native modules hence the error.It will only work in pure react native apps.

You can check this by expo itself : [expo-device](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/device/#devicemodelid)

hopeit helps.feel free for doubts

Comment: there is no property to get device id in above link. So how can we get it for expo apps?

Comment: Do you see a device id/token in that link you've sent?

Answer (score 3):

You **can** use `react-native-device-info` even in Expo projects. You need to replace Expo Go with a *custom* build that has `react-native-device-info` library baked in.

By default, [Expo Go](https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/#expo-go-app-for-android-and-ios) used on Android, iPhone Emulators implies [managed workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/) (aka only `expo-*` modules are being used). However, using any pure `react-native-*` libraries falls under [bare workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/), so you cannot use Expo Go - the error you see is from Expo Go, not your app.

1. [Build your custom Expo app](https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/) with `expo-dev-client`, `react-native-device-info` libraries included, and install that on your emulators. This needs to be done once when you add a `react-native-*` library.
2. Now continue to add code to your project that uses features from `react-native-device-info`.
3. `npx expo start --dev-client` and choose your emulator. [Your custom build will be launched](https://docs.expo.dev/development/use-development-builds/) and you can make live changes as always like in Expo Go.

Do check out the section on [Development Builds](https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/) from Expo. Needless to say, I have *successfully* used `react-native-device-info` on my Expo project, because `expo-device` cannot provide [what I needed](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#api).